# How can I sum a column with a boolean secondary column

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

With this kind of Google Docs Spreadsheet:

[image]

How can I calculate SUM(C1:C8), but without values where the corresponding D column has a 0 (so, without C1 and C3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=SUMIF(D1:D8, "<>0", C1:C8)
```

Not described in the help is the use of `<>`. This reads as `not equal`

The rest is explained in the help:

- **[SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en-GB&rd=1)**

Comment: Perfect, just does the trick! :)